# Colum margin in highchart multiple series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with 3 series, you can see image.

My problem is 3 column is be overlapped.

So anyone can help me fix this.

Thanks!

[image: chart]

Comment: Use [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointRange) to define column size

Comment: thanks @SebastianBochan. It work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointRange) to define column size.

```
plotOptions: {
   series:{
      pointRange: 5000 // 5s
   }
}
```